How to use predictive text on Android phone
Question: How do you accept the suggested text in a cell phone? For example, as shown in the screenshot below, when I am typing Are you go..., the android is anticipating Are you going to... (pay attention to greyed out part ing to)

In my Microsoft WORD document, I have predictive text feature turned on. Editor anticipates my next words and suggests words or phrases as I type. To accept the suggested text, I press the Tab or Right-arrow key on my keyboard and keep typing.
I noticed that my Google Fi cell phone also has the same feature where it anticipates my next words and suggests words or phrases as I type. But I do not know how to accept the suggested text. The cell phone does not have tab or right-arrow key. I suppose there must be an alternative way of doing the same in a cell phone.

swipe right on the text

@phuclv Your suggestion worked. I would suggest that you convert your comment/suggestion to a response (a solution) with brief details. And I will then mark your response as a solution. This will help the readers of this post - a green tick mark generally helps readers since they know that OP has accepted the solution. Thank you.
